# unrestrictedTraverse gets the wrong object when there is two adjacent identical ids

Tags: plone

I have:

```
try:
    path1 = /Plone/s/a
    path2 = 2011/07/07
    #The path to traverse becomes /Plone/s/a/2011/07/07/. From
    #Plone to last 07, they are normal Folders.
    ob = self.portal.unrestrictedTraverse('%s/%s/' % (path1, path2))
    print ob
except AtributeError:
    #do something
    pass
```

**/Plone/s/a/2011/07/07/** doesn't exist. **/Plone/s/a/2011/07/** exists. The code above is supposed to give an AtributeError, but I get **/Plone/s/a/2011/07/** object instead. It prints:

```
<ATFolder at /Plone/s/a/2011/07 used for /Plone/s/a/2011/07>
```

I don't want to get a "similar" result from the traverse, this is wrong. I need specifically **/Plone/s/a/2011/07/07/**. If it doesn't exists, I want to catch the exception .

Which other approaches can I use to see if there's an object exactly at **/Plone/s/a/2011/07/07/**, and not *close enough* like **/Plone/s/a/2011/07/**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You hit acquisition.

You want to get the '07' element/property/attribute of the '07' folder. But this last one doesn't have a sub-object with that id. So , due to acquisition, the existing '07' folder asks to its parent element if it has a sub-object with the mentioned id, and of course, '2011' folder has that element, the '07' one you are sitting on.

This is a rough explanation of how acquisition works.

Another example is this URL:
http://plone.org/news/news/news/news/news/events

The 'events' folder doesn't really *live* in 'news' folder. And all those 'news' folders aren't really there, but there is at least one 'news' folder living in plone.org root, and although it doesn't have an 'events' folder, its parent (plone.org again) does.

Here you have some references:

- http://plone.org/documentation/glossary/acquisition
- http://docs.zope.org/zope2/zope2book/Acquisition.html

If you want to make sure an element/property/attribute is really part of the parent element you should use `aq_base` from `Acquisition`:

```
from Acquisition import aq_base

plone = aq_base(self.portal.Plone)
s = aq_base(getattr(plone, 's'))
a = aq_base(getattr(s, 'a'))
year = aq_base(getattr(a, '2011'))
month = aq_base(getattr(year, '07'))
day = aq_base(getattr(month, '07'))
```

`aq_base` strips the acquisition chain from the element so no acquisition will be used to get its elements.

Comment: Surely you're getting your parameters backwards:
`year = aq_base(getattr('2011', a))`
should be:
`year = aq_base(getattr(a,'2011'))`

Otherwise, well put.  The OP may not like it, but acquisition is a vital part of Zope, and a whole lot of stuff would break if we stopped using it!

Comment: @marcosfromero: I knew it would be acquisition, I just wanted to know how I could resolve this problem. So instead of using unrestrictedTraverse, I can use aq_base and getattr. The snippet you posted is really self explanatory. It seens to be a good solution. And I know acquisition is vital @Auspex, and thanks for the correction.

Comment: day now has no acquisition context and absolute URL generation and other services will fail...

Comment: @Auspex: thank you, I corrected the snippeet of code. @somebody-still-uses-you-ms-dos: it didn't understand from your question that you knew about acquisition "The code above is supposed to give an AtributeError", that's why I explained that. @martijn-pieters: Good point, thank you.

Comment: @marcosfromero: Don't mind, you answer hit the nail in the head.

Comment: @Martijn Pieters: I couldn't understand your warning. Are you saying `aq_base` is not going to work on `day` variable since it has no acquisition context?

Comment: @Somebody: No, the resulting 'day' object will not have an acquisition context, because it was stripped when retrieving it. Which means that calls like `day.getPhysicalPath()` will fail.

Comment: @Martijn Pieters: Thanks for reporting this problem. Indeed I need to read more about all of these concepts.

Comment: @martijn-pieters: Yes, you're right. The question didn't say anything about using the final "day" object to get its path, that's why I didn't care about that. However, it is really useful to be aware of what you say.